# Horizontal position change due to inserted vspace

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, titles

I'm not sure why the horizontal position of the "date" (`\Date{\today}`) is changing when I add a `vspace{x}` in a separate line directly beneath it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! (not-very-minimal working example attached below)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{parskip}

%title stuff
\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\LARGE{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Subtitle}[1]{\large{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Date}[1]{\textsf{\textmd{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Author}[1]{\textsf{\textmd{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fancyAuthor}[1]{\textsf{\textmd{\textit{#1}}}}

%vector stuff
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}


\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.1cm}

\begin{center}
\Title{Quaternions and 3D Rotation}

\Subtitle{A Maths Exploration}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\Date{\today}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

p.s. as can be seen in the "not-very-MWE", `\Date` is a new command defined in the preamble.

Comment: If you really need to work with these `\vspace`s, put a `%` at the ends of the lines to prevent spurious spaces: `\vspace{0.5cm}%
\Date{\today}%
\vspace{0.5cm}%`.

Comment: Unrelated, commands like `\Large` does not take arguments, so you're better of moving it inside Title etc

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat better to use  a blank line

Comment: `\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\LARGE{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}}`  means that after `\Title` _the rest of the document_ (or the rest of the current enviornment is in `\LARGE` text. That is presumably not intended.

Answer (score 1):

You should not normally have `\vspace` in a document (the layout of the title is normally specified elsewhere by your document class) but if you do use it,  always put a blank line before it so you are already in vertical mode.

As it is you have the same effect as ending the line `zzz {}`  which puts a space at the end of the text so changes the centering